# How do I fix my bash command to make a year-based hierarchy of my photos using symlinks?

Tags: bash, environment-variables, symbolic-link, xargs

I'm new to bash and I'm having problems with using variables in xargs I think.

```
imanuel@orangepipc:~$ find /media/et10000 -name '*' -exec file {} \; | grep -o -P '^.+: \w+ image' | cut -d':' -f1 | xargs -I {} sh -c "fname="{}"; echo 'filename:'; echo $fname; filebase=$(basename $fname); filenew=${fname:14}; mkdir --parents /media/newhdd/photos$(dirname $fnamenew); cp -dv $fname /media/newhdd/photos$fnamenew; ln -s /media/newhdd/photos/year/$(date +%Y)/$fnamebase /media/newhdd/photos$fnamenew"
```

I get this error for every photo until I press ^C.

```
filename:

mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/home/imanuel/photos’: File exists
cp: missing destination file operand after ‘/home/imanuel/photos’
Try 'cp --help' for more information.
ln: failed to create symbolic link ‘/home/imanuel/photos/2016’: File exists
```

So the problem is that the fname variable doesn't seem to get set, whatever I try. I tried putting double quotes around {}, around $fname and replace the outer two double quotes with '.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure while you using xarg but there might be many ways to Rome as usual. here my approach for example:

```
#!/bin/bash

SRCDIR="$HOME/Pictures/."     # should be : /media/et10000
DST="."                                       # should be : /media/newhdd/photos
find ${SRCDIR} -type f -exec file {} \; | grep -o -P '^.+: \w+ image' | cut -d':' -f1|while read fname
do
 echo "FILE:    ${fname}"
 filebase=$(dirname $fname);
 filenew=$(basename "$fname");
 echo "filenew: ${filenew}"
 ## place here all the mkdir, copy and link BUT take care that
 ## white spaces and other chars needs to be masked - so place your
 ## variable into this exact way: "${varname}" like
 ## ln -s "/media/newhdd/photos/year/$(date +%Y)/${fnamebase}"
 echo "---"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

The OP uses double quotes for the argument to `sh -c`, which causes the parent shell to do variable and command substitutions. E.g., `"...; echo $fname; ..."` will be substituted by the parent shell into `"...; echo ; ..."` because the parent shell doesn't know `$fname`.

If you insist on using `xargs` (instead of `while read -r line`), I suggest using single quotes for the outter-most quote level, double quotes for the next quote level, then `\"` for the third level if needed.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the all-in-one command. And then I turned it into bash script. Any suggestions on making it more readable are welcome though. :D

```
#!/bin/sh
find "$1" -name '*' -exec file {} \; | grep -o -P '^.+: \w+ image' | cut -d':' -f1 | xargs -I {} sh -c "fname={}; filebase=\$(basename \$fname); fnamenew=\${fname#$1}; mkdir --parents /media/newhdd/photos\$(dirname \$fnamenew); cp -dv \$fname /media/newhdd/photos\$fnamenew; mkdir --parents /media/newhdd/photos/year/\$(date +%Y); ln -fs /media/newhdd/photos\$fnamenew /media/newhdd/photos/year/\$(date +%Y)/\$fnamebase; mkdir --parents /media/newhdd/photos/year/\$(date +%Y/%m-%B); ln -fs /media/newhdd/photos\$fnamenew /media/newhdd/photos/year/\$(date +%Y/%m-%B)/\$fnamebase;"
```

The main problems with the script were these:

- I didn't escape the dollar signs, so I replaced every `$` with `\$`.
- I accidentally typed filenew instead of fnamenew and the substring functionality wasn't available in Dash (Debian Almquist Shell), so I changed `filenew=\${fname:14};` into `fnamenew=\${fname#$1};`.
- I originally put double quotes around {}, but that was a typo. :)